# Getting "400 Bad Request" when I post shipping status to Shopify

Tags: java, shopify

I try to send the shipping status to Shopify but I get:

> 400 bad request error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "9a4d5c56a7edf1ac5bb17aa1c");
headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());

HttpEntity formEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("https://mysite.myshopify.com/admin/orders/406287121/fulfillments.json",HttpMethod.POST,  formEntity,String.class);
System.out.println("Response="+responseEntity.getBody());
```

Comment: **Do not post any of your sensitive tokens here.** Users on the internet will take that token and can cause harm to you and your business.

Comment: That aside, 400 usually means "bad request".  Are you sure that your request is well-formed?